# Javascript / JQuery Sorting out div by text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list which looks like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="media">
            <span class="label label-success pull-right">10</span>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="img.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">name here</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="media">
            <span class="label label-success pull-right">7</span>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="img.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">name here too</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="media">
            <span class="label label-success pull-right">3</span>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="img.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">name here </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are 3 items in this list as you can see.
There is a `<span>` with class label that contain a number, the three of them do.

I need to have a toggle the ordering by these numbers Asc and Desc ...

How can I do this? Would it be easier if I wrapped the list-group-item div's in `<li>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the elements in question, [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them in the appropriate direction, then [append them to](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) their container (where the append operation will *move* existing elements).

So a little something like this:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {

  var direction = $(this).data("dir")
  $(this).data("dir", direction * -1)
    .text("Sort (" + (direction == 1 ? "desc" : "asc") + ")")

  $("div.list-group-item").sort(function(a,b) {
    return ($(a).find("span.label").text() - $(b).find("span.label").text()) * direction
  }).appendTo(".list-group")
  
})
```

```css
div.list-group-item div { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-dir="1">Sort (asc)</button>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="media">
            <span class="label label-success pull-right">10</span>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="img.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">name here for 10</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="media">
            <span class="label label-success pull-right">7</span>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="img.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">name here too (7)</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="media">
            <span class="label label-success pull-right">3</span>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="img.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">name here for 3</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `-` and `*` operators both coerce their operands to numbers.